# Find closest nodes in binary search tree

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I want to have a collection of objects, sorted by some numerical property, `val`. I want to be able to retrieve all objects matching where `val` matches some value, say, `x`, or if no objects exist with property `val` matching `x`, find the objects with the nearest `val` above and below `x`. (Multiple objects may have the same values for `val`)

One of the few BST libraries I've found is [dsjslib](https://github.com/monmohan/dsjslib). It has what it calls a `TreeMultiMap` which holds multiple values for a single key. The problem is I can't see how I could retrieve nodes closest to `x` if there are no exact matches.

How might I go about this? Browser support for ES6 seems to be coming a long way, so perhaps I could use its `Map` for this?

Comment: "the nearest above and below" above and below what? the number x is not equal to?

Comment: Nearest are the last node you checked and got blocked at - because you can't go down the tree anymore, as it's either missing a required child, or is a leaf - and possibly it's parent. I can give a better explanation of that later today, but it all comes down to observations that can be made about BSTs

Comment: I modified my answer such that when not found it returns a negated value of the expected index of the missing item. This helps you to easily pinpoint the nearest upper and lower neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are after binary search. I had developed a binary `findIndex` method for Arrays which works in sorted arrays of course. It takes a callback and with the help of it a sorted array of objects can also be searched. Since it is binary search it is much faster than the standard `findIndex` or `indexOf` methods.

The default callback is `x => x` which makes it handle sorted primitives by default if no callback is provided. With it's current state if it finds the searched object it returns it's index but if not it will return -1. If the searched it can easily be modified to return the indices of proximity. I can add that later if you require.

```js
Array.prototype.sortedFindIndex = function(val, cb = x => x) { // default callback for primitive arrays
  var deli = this.length-1,                                    // delta index
      base = 0;                                                // base to add the delta index
  while (deli > 0 && cb(this[base + deli]) != val) {
    deli = ~~(deli/2);
    cb(this[base + deli]) < val && (base += deli);
  }
  return cb(this[base + deli]) === val ? base + deli : -1;
};

arr = [{a:0,b:"foo"},{a:1,b:"bar"},{a:2,b:"baz"},{a:3,b:"qux"},{a:4,b:"fox"},{a:5,b:"pun"},{a:6,b:"alf"}],
idx = arr.sortedFindIndex(4, o => o.a);

console.log(idx);
```

And here is a modified version which handles failure cases more cleverly. If the searched item can not be found, the following snippet will return a negated value of the index where it should have existed. Tricky part. It will return a negative zero (-0) if the missing item should be inserted at index 0. Now it should be a piece of cake to find the upper and lower proximity of a non existent item.

```js
Array.prototype.sortedFindIndex = function(val, cb = x => x) { // default callback for primitive arrays
  var            deli = this.length-1,                         // delta index
                 base = 0,                                     // base to add the delta index
      calculatedValue = cb(this[base + deli]),                 // use callback and get the value
           expectedAt = i => { while (this[i] !== void 0 && cb(this[i]) < val) ++i;
                               return -i};
  while (deli > 0 && calculatedValue != val) {
    deli = ~~(deli/2);
    (calculatedValue = cb(this[base + deli])) < val && (base += deli);
  }
  return calculatedValue === val ? base + deli : expectedAt(base + deli);
};

arr = [{a:0,b:"foo"},{a:1,b:"bar"},{a:2,b:"baz"},{a:3,b:"qux"},{a:4,b:"fox"},{a:5,b:"pun"},{a:6,b:"alf"},{a:7,b:"alf"},{a:8,b:"alf"},{a:9,b:"alf"},{a:10,b:"alf"},{a:11,b:"alf"},{a:13,b:"alf"}],
idx = arr.sortedFindIndex(12, o => o.a);

console.log(idx);
```

Comment: Thanks - but your code is not very clear. How does it maintain order? It doesn't look like a binary search tree